# Powershell Get-Verb installation lacking some features

Tags: powershell, windows-10

Completely new to Powershell, using the default installation on Windows 10.

On my system, running `Get-Verb` gives me:

```
> Get-Verb un*                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Verb       Group
----       -----
Undo       Common
Unlock     Common
Unpublish  Data
Uninstall  Lifecycle
Unregister Lifecycle
Unblock    Security
Unprotect  Security
```

which is different from that from the tutorial I was watching (on Pluralsight) and on the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-verb?view=powershell-7):

```
> Get-Verb un*
Verb       AliasPrefix Group     Description
----       ----------- -----     -----------
Undo       un          Common    Sets a resource to its previous state
Unlock     uk          Common    Releases a resource that was locked
Unpublish  ub          Data      Makes a resource unavailable to others
Uninstall  us          Lifecycle Removes a resource from an indicated location
Unregister ur          Lifecycle Removes the entry for a resource from a repository
Unblock    ul          Security  Removes restrictions to a resource
Unprotect  up          Security  Removes safeguards from a resource that were added to prevent it from attack or loss
```

I've also noticed that some other features seem to be missing, such as certain attributes; I am getting the error:

```
> Get-Verb -Group Security | Format-List

Get-Verb : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Group'.
At line:1 char:10
+ get-verb -Group Security | format-list
+          ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Verb], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Get-Verb
```

when in the manpages and the tutorial, the use of the `-Group` option is valid. My manpage seems to be missing the `-Group` option, i.e. it looks like this (compare with the version from the documentation):

```
> man Get-Verb

NAME
    Get-Verb

SYNOPSIS


SYNTAX
    Get-Verb [[-verb] <String[]>] [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION


RELATED LINKS
    https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=160712

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help Get-Verb -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help Get-Verb -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help Get-Verb -full".
    For online help, type: "get-help Get-Verb -online"
```

What is the cause of this discrepancy?

Other details (may or may not be relevant):

- I installed .NET core and the RSAT tools recently, but I don't think they should cause this problem.
- I'm using Windows 10 Education N.
- Output of `$PSVersionTable`:

  ```
  Name                           Value
  ----                           -----
  PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752
  PSEdition                      Desktop
  PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
  BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752
  CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
  WSManStackVersion              3.0
  PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
  SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the more descriptive output for `Get-Verb` is for PowerShell Core (6+). Windows PowerShell (the one installed on Windows by default; 5.1 or lower) does not provide that functionality.

Unfortunately, there seems to be discrepancy on the documentation site. It does not reflect the proper usage if you use the dropdown to switch to PS 5.1.

Comment: I didn't notice the versioning, but it looks gives this error when selecting 5.1. "The requested page is not available for PowerShell 5.1. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for." That may very well be the case, thank you. I wasn't aware of Powershell core before now.

Comment: Update: installing Powershell Core (7.0.1) gave the correct output.